# Where are current flowing in a permanent magnet?

Tags: magnetic-fields, quantum-spin, material-science, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

We know that moving charges produce magnetic fields if then all elements have electron with some non zero angular momentum so all substances must be magnetic to some extend.But this does not happen. But Only few substances are permanent magnet. I am confused why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many requirements for a permanent magnet.

Yes, individual electrons have a magnetic moment.  But many atoms have electrons in pairs.  When all are paired up, the moments cancel and the atom as a whole has no moment to contribute.  So only certain elements can be ferromagnetic.

Next, it must be thermodynamically stable for the moments of neighboring atoms to align.  If the atoms are paired up in opposite directions, or if all the atoms are in random alignments, there will be no bulk ferromagnetism.  This is true of most materials.

For bulk iron below the Curie point, the aligned state is favored.  Groups of atoms (domains) have aligned moments.  If you can get the domains to all point in similar directions, the bulk material will behave as a permanent magnet.

There are different types of iron ore.  Magnetite is one form and although it's an oxide rather than the pure metal, it can still exhibit bulk moments.  But another common form is hematite.  This form has the iron atoms arranged in such a way that it is favorable for the moments to cancel each other ([antiferromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiferromagnetism)) and the material is not magnetic.

Answer (score 1):

Not all permanent magnets require a flowing current. An isolated electron is a permanent magnet, with magnetic moment associated with its spin, but there is no current flowing inside or around an electron (in fact, an electron is a point particle - there is no substructure).

Comment: Electron itself is a wave hence it cant exist in a particular location hence produces a magnetic field is my anology right?

Comment: No. The average position and velocity of an electron can be zero. There may be fluctuations around the averages, with the minimum value given by the uncertainty principle.

Comment: It is better to say that **no model** exists that explains particle spin and associated magnetic moment in terms of motion.